# Windows ComboBox Selected Item (populated from List<>)

Tags: c#, windows, combobox, generic-list, selectedvalue

I am setting a combobox item like this:

```
List<Object> items = new List<Object>();
items.Add(new { Text = "MyVal", Value = 1 });
cbo.DataSource = items;
```

It then in VS returns:

[image]

But I cannot simply now say cbo.SelectedItem.Text or cbo.SelectedItem.Value.
If i try this, I get the error

```
"object does not contain a definition for value and no extension method value 
accepting a first argument of type object could be found"
```

How can I get the Value Property please

Based on great replies, I have now added this, to show that I cannot get the properties of Text or Value at all.
[image]

I've tried this code to pass the "string" into

```
 public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public short Value { get; set; }

        public ComboboxItem(string t, short v)
        {
            Text = t;
            Value = v;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are using it `.Value()` or something? Which line throws this exception? Can we see the relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combo box is bound to a list containing anonymous types. You ought to use the [dynamic keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

```
dynamic item = cbo.SelectedItem;

String text = item.Text;
Int32 value = item.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

create class with Text and Value properties (`ComboboxItem`), then create the `item` list with that class. now you can do as below

```
ComboboxItem obj = cbo.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem;
//now you can get the obj.Value
```

Comment: Hi, I have added code and screenshot to OP please, to show that I tried to do this

Comment: I have updated my answer with the sample code you provide in the question. please note that, you need to get Value property of casted object. not the cbo.SelectedItem

Answer (score 1):

You should add this.`cbo.SelectedItem as object;`
 Then, for example:

```
public class student
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
}
var stu = cbo.SelectedItem as student;
string name = stu.name;
int age = stu.age;
```

OK,this is my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're blanking out certain parts of your code, as of such I shall assume you're not using the object 'object' but something else, else your code wouldn't compile.

The ComboBox does not hold the datatype of its values, it all treats them as simple objects. So SelectedItem will be of type object, which should then be casted to the correct datatype in order to access the text / value property.

```
var myItem = cbo.SelectedItem as MyObject
if(myItem != null){
    Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", myItem.Value);
}
```